# org chart component in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, orgchart

I have got an open source "Organisation Chart" component in Flex from the below link 
http://myflex.googlecode.com/svn/

But the component is in Flex 3, and I want the same in Flex 4.
When I am trying to run the same in Flex 4, 
I am getting some weird errors :

1024: Overriding a function that is not marked for override.   OrgChart.as

Any one has any idea, Please help me with this.
Also If any one knows any other "Org chart" component for Flex4, Please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: After some debugging and help from my co-worker, I finally solved this. The error is due to the name of the function "_depth", which might be a core function in Flex 4.5 SDK. So just need to rename the function from "_depth" to any other name and It will work smoothly in Flex 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you looked at the [home page for the component](http://code.google.com/p/myflex/), you would notice that it has a link to 
[this component](http://code.google.com/p/cubecomponents/), which seems to be a version of an OrgChart in flex 4 (extending skinnable container, etc).

Answer (score 0):

you should
change the name   depth

```
in - IOrgChartNode
   - DefaultOrgChartNode
   - OrgChart
```

and it will work